# Showing AngularJS $timeout progress bar

Tags: angularjs, timeout, progress-bar

I have a alert message that I want to hide after a while. I use $timeout and it works well. However, I want to add a small horizontal count-down (aka progress) bar at the bottom of this alert box to let the user know that their time is running out.

AngularJS $timeout doesn't seem to have any way to determine how long it has been running. How should I update my progressbar in this case?

I use the $timeout like this

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.m.hideAlertMessage = true;
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$interval` to run on every second and update the counter scope variable, and when it gets to 10 you can kill the interval and do whatever you wanted to do.

E.g.

```
$scope.counter = 0;
$interval(function() {
    $scope.counter++;
    if($scope.counter == 10) {
        // Do whatever you wanted
    }
}, 1000, 10);
```

The third argument of `$interval` is the # of times to run.

Note that by default this is run in an iteration of `$scope.$apply()` so the changes to `$scope.counter` will be immediately visible in your view.